Questions on backpropagation in a neural net
I understand how to symbolically apply back propagation, calculate the formulas with pen and paper. When it comes to actually using these derivations on data, I have 2 questions:

Suppose certain gradient looks like $o_i \times w_{i,j}$, where $o_i$ is the output of the $i$-th neuron, and $w_{i,j}$ is one of its weights. Now I have a batch of data point, $o_i$ has different value for each one of them, so how do I calculate it numerically? Do I just average over all my data points in that batch?
In other words: assuming I define the error (at the very end) as an average, does that averaging (expected value) just propagate together with the rest of the backpropagation, and everywhere I see dependence of the input data, I just plug in averaging operator?
Can someone provide some intuition on this? How I see it is, because the error is in the "numerator" of all gradients, whatever we do with it, be it averaging or summing, can naively just propagate backward, and you just do that operator (e.g. averaging) over all terms you see. And if you have a constant (e.g. a weight) it doesn't do anything, if you have an output, you average over the batch. Is that decent explanation?

If we have an earlier neuron $N$, that appears twice as input in later layers, when doing back propagation, we can just do $+=$ on its derivative the 2nd time we encounter it, i.e. we can naively add up the various gradient contributions. But this neuron could participate in different ways in those subsequent neurons, they may have different mathematical expressions etc. And yet we can just naively add up all its gradients, how does this work?
It's a nice property, but I don't understand how it works out so simply without any issues. Can someone offer intuitive explanation? It seems to have to do with how "back propagation works in chunks, individual steps so exact dependence shouldn't matter", that's the level of my current understanding.



here is an example description of the batch approach https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/266977/

the questions are very dense. I would split this into multiple postings with descriptive headlines

That post describes the last step though, not how it propagates in the deeper layers, unless I'm missing something?

It’s the chain rule. It’s just the chain rule. You can search the site for questions about backprop and all of them mention the chain rule.

The answers to both of your questions are "because of the chain rule". This will be more clear with examples.
Backprop doesn't care about batches
In other words, if you were to implement backprop in software, you won't need to explicitly encode any concept of the "batch"; you won't do any explicit aggregation over the batch dimension. In backprop, there are only matrices/vectors and their gradients which are synthesized via the chain rule. (Aside: gradient accumulation does care about batches. See this discussion.)
Let's go through backprop for linear regression, where $X$ is our $n \times d$ data matrix: there are $n$ observations in this batch, each with $d$ features. The labels in our batch, $\mathbf{y}$, are $n \times 1$. The weights of our model, $\mathbf{w}$, are $d \times 1$.
$$
\mathbf{\hat{y}} = X\mathbf{w} \\
l = || \mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y} ||_2^2 \: .
$$
By the chain rule, we want:
$$
\frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{w} } = \frac{ \partial \mathbf{\hat{y}} }{ \partial \mathbf{w} } \frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{\hat{y}} }.
$$
We have—
$$
\frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{\hat{y}} } = 2(\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y})
$$
—from the last computation in backprop (we're going backwards from $l$). And we have (in denominator layout)—
$$
\frac{ \partial \mathbf{\hat{y}} }{ \partial \mathbf{w} } = X^T
$$
—because it's the gradient for the matrix-vector dot-product: $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = X\mathbf{w}$.
So we have:
$$
\frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{w} } = X^T 2(\mathbf{\hat{y}} - \mathbf{y}).
$$
Looking at the $j$'th component of the gradient will help in answering your question:
$$
\bigg( \frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{w} } \bigg)_j = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (X^T)_{ji} \: 2(\hat{y}_i - y_i).
$$
The $j$'th component of the gradient is, internally, an aggregation over the $j$'th feature column of $X$—the $j$'th feature for all observations in our batch.
To review, the aggregation over observations in our batch happened because of the chain rule: the derivative of the loss wrt the weights of this layer is the product of (1) the derivative of the loss wrt this layer's activations/outputs and (2) the derivative of this layer's activations/outputs wrt the weights. The former derivative will be $n \times m$ (where $m$ is anything) because of the aggregation in the loss; each component of this gradient corresponds to an observation in the batch of $n$. The latter derivative is a function of the previous layer's activations/outputs (the inputs to this layer). And it's $n \times m'$ (where $m'$ is anything) because that's how batching works—each observation gets its own encoding before and after each layer. Multiplying these derivatives internally performs aggregation over the $n$ observations in our batch. We only needed to go over a single layer to convey this point. If you repeat this analysis for another, previous layer, you'll see the same pattern. And if the loss is an average, you should be able to see that a $1/n$ term is back-propagated to $\frac{ \partial l }{ \partial \mathbf{w} }$ by the chain rule.
Why += works
Consider this computation graph:
       a
     /   \
    b     c
   / \   / \
  d    e    f

Intuitively, we want to know how much a wiggles by wiggling e. Imagine we wiggle e. a will wiggle from two wiggling paths. b will wiggle a bit (db/de), and that causes a to wiggle a bit (da/db). (The chain rule says that these two wiggles need to be multiplied to get the effect of wiggling e on a through b.) Independently, c will wiggle a bit (dc/de), and that causes a to wiggle a bit (da/dc).  The fact that the two wiggling paths are independent is why we can add them to get the total wiggle on a by wiggling e: da/de = (da/db)(db/de) + (da/dc)(dc/de). We can include more independent paths, and just have to add the path's marginal wiggle effect via +=.
Mathematically, it's this case of the chain rule.

Thank you very much for the great explanation. I have 2 follow up questions/comments:


For question 1. to make sure I understand correctly: in applying the chain rule, when we encounter a term like d(neuron_output)/d(its_weights), the "numerator" is a matrix (with as many rows as data points in the batch), and the calculation proceeds. If loss is averaged out, the average will propagate into terms of the form dL/d(neuron_out).


What still bothers me here is, we might have a=b+c, or a=bc, and the rule is still valid? Can you please expand on this?




Yes, the aggregation in the loss will be propagated to the weights through dL/d(neuron_out). Exercise: add sample-weighting to the loss and re-calculate the derivatives.



a = b + c vs a = bc only changes da/db and da/dc; the equation for da/de still holds. The chain rule has 2 rules for synthesizing derivatives: (1) if variables are on the same path, multiply their partials (intuition) (2) if there are multiple, independent (or maybe we should say mutually exclusive) paths, add their derivatives (video)


Thank you, I've learned so much from your answers. One open question in my mind is, how do you "decide" to transpose X below "So we have:". Above it's not transposed, but you decided to transpose it. Thanks

The math is in denominator layout. This convention makes sense for training NNs b/c we want to do gradient descent => storing the gradient, dl/dw, in denominator layout let's us just subtract. (My answer could be re-written to avoid matrix calculus. But backprop software uses matrix calculus, so I thought I'd use it.)
